# How to handle on close event of a programmatically created Form in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, forms

I am new to VB.NET and I'm stuck with the following:

I want to perform some operations before a programmatically-created Form closes.

I need to handle the Close event of my Form (created in code).

How can I do this?

Below is how they do it with C#

```cs
{
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    f.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(f_FormClosed);
    f.Show();
}

void f_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: VB and C# share the exact same object events, since they use the same libraries (give or take).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB.NET events are handled a little bit differently. 
If you want to use the `Handles` clause in addition to the form's `FormClosed` delegate declaration, you need to declare the object (`Form` in your case) with the `WithEvents` key word at a *module level*:

```
Private WithEvents frmX AS New Form
```

Then you can just write:

```
Private Sub frmX_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles frmX.FormClosed

End Sub
```

The compiler will then take care of attaching and detaching the handler as appropriate.

If you want to take control yourself, then declare the `Form` wherever you'd like and use the `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler` directives as appropriate:

```
// Define the handler delegate as usual:
Private Sub frmX_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs)

End Sub

// Somewhere else in your code use this:

// To attach the handler:
AddHandler frmX.FormClosed, AddressOf Form5_FormClosed

// To detach the handler:
RemoveHandler frmX.FormClosed, AddressOf frmX_FormClosed
```

The `.FormClosed` will popup in the `AddHandler` / `RemoveHandler` context.
Note the `AddressOf` keyword. It is mandatory when you need to specify a delegate.

Comment: Your first statement is not correct. You only need `WithEvents` if you're going to use the [**Handles clause**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y(v=vs.140).aspx). It is perfectly possible to subscribe to events to dynamically created controls, just like in his C# example.

Comment: @VisualVincent: In VB, _module level_ is generalization of _class level_. In VB6 the exact term is _class module_, _form module_, etc. Also it is perfectly fine to declare and maintain a form in a module too. You're right for the `WithEvents` though; it seems I'm  a bit rusty in VB.NET ...

Comment: I just read about module level (seems to be different explanations for different VB versions), but you were correct that it's the same as Class level. So I removed my second comment.

Answer (score 1):

*"but FormClosed in C# Form isn't available in vb.NET"* - Infact it is, but events aren't generally shown by the IntelliSense if you aren't currently in a statement requiring an event.

In VB.NET you use the [**AddHandler statement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) to subscribe to events.

```vb
Dim f As New Form1
AddHandler f.FormClosed, AddressOf f_FormClosed
f.Show()

...

Private Sub f_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As System.FormClosedEventArgs)

End Sub
```